# Merge two Y**0.5 gate into a single Y gate

Tags: programming, cirq

How can I merge two consecutive `cirq.Y**0.5` gates into a single `cirq.Y` gate with a transformer?

I can use `cirq.merge_k_qubit_unitaries` to merge the two gate but the result is not a `cirq.EigenGate` anymore. I want to keep the EigenGate type after the transformation.

Comment: You should multiply that by a global phase gate I think

Answer (score 0):

A flexible way is to use the [`cirq.merge_operations`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/e5a11b6fd77199f1655c7087267bb660ee349be7/cirq-core/cirq/transformers/transformer_primitives.py#L279) transformer which lets you pass in your own merge function that decides what operations to merge and how. For example:

```
def merge_func(op1: cirq.Operation, op2: cirq.Operation) -> Optional[cirq.Operation]:
    if not isinstance(op1, cirq.GateOperation):
        return None
    if not isinstance(op2, cirq.GateOperation):
        return None
    if not isinstance(op1.gate, cirq.YPowGate):
        return None
    if not isinstance(op2.gate, cirq.YPowGate):
        return None

    return cirq.Y(*op1.qubits)**(op1.gate.exponent + op2.gate.exponent)

circuit = cirq.merge_operations(circuit, merge_func)
```